# Php and regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to get some data with php from a string which is between parenthesis ().

I'm trying to use regular expression with the function preg_split().

```
string = franco (franco@gmail.com), juan (juan@gmail.com), dario (dario@gmail.com), laura (guzman@gmail.com).
```

which would be the regular expression to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
$string = 'franco (franco@gmail.com), juan (juan@gmail.com), dario (dario@gmail.com), laura (guzman@gmail.com).';

preg_match_all('/\(\K[^)]+/', $string, $m);
print_r($m[0]);
```

**Regex Breakup:**

```
\(    # match a literal (
\K    # reset matched information
[^)]+ # match 1 or more characters that is not )
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => franco@gmail.com
    [1] => juan@gmail.com
    [2] => dario@gmail.com
    [3] => guzman@gmail.com
)
```

Comment: it woks great! Thank you very much!

Comment: Done, thx for your time